# Error:Input string was not in a correct format. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, document-library, sharepoint-online, content-type, list-item

I'm using SharePoint 2013 online and trying to save an item to a folder content type in a document library I think the code is nearly right but I am getting this error when I hit save button have anyone else had this problem?

```
Failed Error: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Error on this line.

```
appContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
```

This is my function ctName is global.

```
ctName = 'IFUSimon';
function createListItem() {

console.log("1");
if (itemId == 'null') {

    var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    listCreationInformation.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
    var folderName = $('#Title').val();
    if (folderName != "") {
        listCreationInformation.set_leafName(folderName);
    } else {
        alert('No title');
        return false;
    }
    listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);
    console.log("3");
    var listContentTypes = list.get_contentTypes();
    console.log("4");
    appContext.load(listContentTypes);
    console.log("5");
    appContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log("6");
        var ct;
        console.log("7");
        var ct_enumerator = listContentTypes.getEnumerator();
        console.log("8");
        while (ct_enumerator.moveNext()) {
            ct = ct_enumerator.get_current();
            if (ct.get_name() == ctName) {
                CTID = ct.get_id();
            }
        }
        listItem.set_item('ContentTypeId', CTID);

        console.log("kmr du hitsnart");
        setItems();
        console.log("kmr du hitsnartklarrrr");
    }, fail);  
}
else {

    listItem = item;
    console.log("2");
    setItems();
}
}
```

Log from chrome console

```
1
3
4
5
Failed Error: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

**UPDATE**

I have a very long survey and I am trying to set the item when I save to my content type that is based on folder to set the fields I have used textarea and then

```
 .set_item('SharePoint column', $('#my textarea').val())
```

and the thing is when I press save in SharePoint on the survey I it save all data just like I want and I can read it back the only thing is that it's set it to wrong content type. And I get Failed Error: Input string was not in a correct format. and it still goes in success.

here is my code to set items

```
function setItems() {
    createListItem();
    console.log("15")
    listItem.set_item('Title', $('#Title').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment', $('#GEN_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment_D', $('#GEN_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname', $('#GEN_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname_D', $('#GEN_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_3_F_Mapp', $('#GEN_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_3_F_Mapp_D', $('#GEN_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_4_File_Prio', $('#GEN_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_4_File_Prio_D', $('#GEN_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_5_City', $('#GEN_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_5_City_D', $('#GEN_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_6_During_Operation', $('#GEN_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_6_During_Operation_D', $('#GEN_6_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_7_Redundancy_Requirements', $('#GEN_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_7_Redundancy_Requirements_D', $('#GEN_7_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_8_Load', $('#GEN_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_8_Load_D', $('#GEN_8_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_9_Dimensioned_Effect', $('#GEN_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_9_Dimensioned_Effect_D', $('#GEN_9_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_10_Rack_nr_Size', $('#GEN_10').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_10_Rack_nr_Size_D', $('#GEN_10_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_11_Sketch_Design', $('#GEN_11').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_11_Sketch_Design_D', $('#GEN_11_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_12_Req_Fire_Class', $('#GEN_12').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_12_Req_Fire_Class_D', $('#GEN_12_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_13_Expansion', $('#GEN_13').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_13_Expansion_D', $('#GEN_13_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_14_Existing_Build', $('#GEN_14').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_14_Existing_Build_D', $('#GEN_14_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_15_Site_Transport', $('#GEN_15').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_15_Site_Transport_D', $('#GEN_15_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_16_Supply_Warranty', $('#GEN_16').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_16_Supply_Warranty_D', $('#GEN_16_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_17_Existing_Equipment', $('#GEN_17').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_17_Existing_Equipment_D', $('#GEN_17_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_18_Net_Force', $('#GEN_18').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_18_Net_Force_D', $('#GEN_18_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_19_BYGG_GOLV', $('input[name="GEN19"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_19_BYGG_GOLV_D', $('#GEN_19_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_20_EL', $('input[name="GEN20"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_20_EL_D', $('#GEN_20_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_21_KYL', $('input[name="GEN21"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_21_KYL_D', $('#GEN_21_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_22_NET', $('input[name="GEN22"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_22_NET_D', $('#GEN_22_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_23_DRI', $('input[name="GEN23"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_23_DRI_D', $('#GEN_23_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_24_BRA', $('input[name="GEN24"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_24_BRA_D', $('#GEN_24_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_25_PERI', $('input[name="GEN25"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_25_PERI_D', $('#GEN_25_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_26_INR', $('input[name="GEN26"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_26_INR_D', $('#GEN_26_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_27_ARBETSMOMENT_RISK', $('#GEN_27').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_27_ARBETSMOMENT_RISK_D', $('#GEN_27_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_28_Info', $('#GEN_28').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_28_Info_D', $('#GEN_28_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_1_Needs', $('#KYL_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_1_Needs_D', $('#KYL_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_2_Moisture_Control', $('#KYL_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_2_Moisture_Control_D', $('#KYL_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_3_Type_Monitor_Interface', $('#KYL_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_3_Type_Monitor_Interface_D', $('#KYL_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_4_Liquid_Alarm_Cable', $('#KYL_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_4_Liquid_Alarm_Cable_D', $('#KYL_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_5_Ventilation', $('#KYL_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_5_Ventilation_D', $('#KYL_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_6_Energy_Saving_Recyckling', $('#KYL_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_6_Energy_Saving_Recyckling_D', $('#KYL_6_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_7_Existin_Cooling_System', $('#KYL_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_7_Existin_Cooling_System_D', $('#KYL_7_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_8_Outside_Placement', $('#KYL_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_8_Outside_Placement_D', $('#KYL_8_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_9_Connection_Points_Border_Demarcation', $('#KYL_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_9_Connection_Points_Border_Demarcation_D', $('#KYL_9_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_10_Floor_Ceiling', $('#KYL_10').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_10_Floor_Ceiling_D', $('#KYL_10_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_11_Info', $('#KYL_11').val());
    listItem.set_item('KYL_11_Info_D', $('#KYL_11_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_1_Effect_Rack', $('#EL_INFRA_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_1_Effect_Rack_D', $('#EL_INFRA_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_2_Rackspaces', $('#EL_INFRA_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_2_Rackspaces_D', $('#EL_INFRA_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_3_Equipment_Outside_Elmatas', $('#EL_INFRA_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_3_Equipment_Outside_Elmatas_D', $('#EL_INFRA_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_4_Floor_Ceiling', $('#EL_INFRA_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_INFRA_4_Floor_Ceiling_D', $('#EL_INFRA_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_1_Time_Battery_Power', $('#EL_UPS_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_1_Time_Battery_Power_D', $('#EL_UPS_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_2_Effect_Operating_Time', $('#EL_UPS_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_2_Effect_Operating_Time_D', $('#EL_UPS_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_3_Battery_Variety', $('#EL_UPS_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_3_Battery_Variety_D', $('#EL_UPS_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_4_Battery_Placement', $('#EL_UPS_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_4_Battery_Placement_D', $('#EL_UPS_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_5_Floor_Type', $('#EL_UPS_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_5_Floor_Type_D', $('#EL_UPS_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_6_Flotation', $('#EL_UPS_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_6_Flotation_D', $('#EL_UPS_6_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_7_Ventilation', $('#EL_UPS_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_7_Ventilation_D', $('#EL_UPS_7_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_8_Cooling_Capacity', $('#EL_UPS_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_8_Cooling_Capacity_D', $('#EL_UPS_8_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_9_Type_Monitor_Interface', $('#EL_UPS_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_9_Type_Monitor_Interface_D', $('#EL_UPS_9_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_10_Battery_Monitoring_Offereras0', $('input[name="ELUPS10"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_10_Battery_Monitoring_Offereras_D', $('#EL_UPS_10_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_11_Software_Solution_Atuomatic_Shutdown', $('#EL_UPS_11').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_UPS_11_Software_Solution_Atuomatic_Shutdown_D', $('#EL_UPS_11_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_1_Placement_Space', $('#EL_RESKR_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_1_Placement_Space_D', $('#EL_RESKR_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_2_Site_Transport', $('#EL_RESKR_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_2_Site_Transport_D', $('#EL_RESKR_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_3_Placement_Emergency_Power', $('#EL_RESKR_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_3_Placement_Emergency_Power_D', $('#EL_RESKR_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_4_Distance_Location_Truck', $('#EL_RESKR_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_4_Distance_Location_Truck_D', $('#EL_RESKR_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_5_Sound_Requirements', $('#EL_RESKR_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_5_Sound_Requirements_D', $('#EL_RESKR_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_6_Operating_Time_Emergency_Power', $('#EL_RESKR_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_6_Operating_Time_Emergency_Power_D', $('#EL_RESKR_6_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_7_Exhaust', $('#EL_RESKR_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_7_Exhaust_D', $('#EL_RESKR_7_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_8_Cable_Length_Substations_Auxiliary_Power_Units', $('#EL_RESKR_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_8_Cable_Length_Substations_Auxiliary_Power_Units_D', $('#EL_RESKR_8_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_9_Control_System_Blink', $('#EL_RESKR_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_9_Control_System_Blink_D', $('#EL_RESKR_9_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_10_Typ_Cooling', $('#EL_RESKR_10').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_ResKr_10_Typ_Cooling_D', $('#EL_RESKR_10_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_11_Info', $('#EL_11').val());
    listItem.set_item('EL_11_Info_D', $('#EL_11_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_1_Drawing', $('#GOLV_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_1_Drawing_D', $('#GOLV_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_2_Height', $('#GOLV_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_2_Height_D', $('#GOLV_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_3_Stringers', $('input[name="GOLV3"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_3_Stringers_D', $('#GOLV_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_4_Cooler_Cutouts', $('#GOLV_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_4_Cooler_Cutouts_D', $('#GOLV_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_5_Ventilation_Plate', $('#GOLV_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_5_Ventilation_Plate_D', $('#GOLV_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_6_Fire_Seals', $('#GOLV_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_6_Fire_Seals_D', $('#GOLV_6_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_7_Entries', $('#GOLV_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_7_Entries_D', $('#GOLV_7_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_8_Stairs', $('#GOLV_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_8_Stairs_D', $('#GOLV_8_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_9_Solid_Ramp', $('#GOLV_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_9_Solid_Ramp_D', $('#GOLV_9_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_10_Aluminium_Ramp', $('input[name="GOLV10"]:checked').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_10_Aluminium_Ramp_D', $('#GOLV_10_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_11_Railing', $('#GOLV_11').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_11_Railing_D', $('#GOLV_11_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_12_Switchgear_Floor', $('#GOLV_12').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_12_Switchgear_Floor_D', $('#GOLV_12_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_13_Glas_Plate', $('#GOLV_13').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_13_Glas_Plate_D', $('#GOLV_13_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('BYGG_1_Build', $('#BYGG_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('BYGG_1_Build_D', $('#BYGG_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_BYGG_1_Info', $('#GOLV_BYGG_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('GOLV_BYGG_1_Info_D', $('#GOLV_BYGG_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_1_Sum_Digital_Alarm', $('#DRI_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_1_Sum_Digital_Alarm_D', $('#DRI_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_2_Sum_Analog_Larm', $('#DRI_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_2_Sum_Analog_Larm_D', $('#DRI_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_3_Liquid_Alarms_Included_Cooling_Solution', $('#DRI_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_3_Liquid_Alarms_Included_Cooling_Solution_D', $('#DRI_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_4_Facility_Remote_Monitored_Localy_Display', $('#DRI_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_4_Facility_Remote_Monitored_Localy_Display_D', $('#DRI_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_5_Alarm_Information_Further', $('#DRI_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_5_Alarm_Information_Further_D', $('#DRI_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_6_Personnel_Servicetype', $("#DRI_6 option:selected").text());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_6_Personnel_Servicetype_D', $('#DRI_6_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_7_Personnel_Notification_How', $('#DRI_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_7_Personnel_Notification_How_D', $('#DRI_7_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_8_Alarm_Supervised_Secure_Line', $('#DRI_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_8_Alarm_Supervised_Secure_Line_D', $('#DRI_8_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_9_Info', $('#DRI_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('DRI_9_Info_D', $('#DRI_9_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_1_Rackspaces', $('#NET_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_1_Rackspaces_D', $('#NET_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_2_Outlet_Rack_Fiber_Copper', $('#NET_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_2_Outlet_Rack_Fiber_Copper_D', $('#NET_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_3_NR_Racks_Passive_Active_Com', $('#NET_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_3_NR_Racks_Passive_Active_Com_D', $('#NET_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_4_Size_KoMM_Rack', $('#NET_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_4_Size_KoMM_Rack_D', $('#NET_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_5_DuctingChoice', $("#NET_5 option:selected").text());
    listItem.set_item('NET_5_Ducting_D', $('#NET_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_6_Customer_Ducting', $('#NET_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_6_Customer_Ducting_D', $('#NET_6_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_7_Network_Design', $('#NET_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_7_Network_Design_D', $('#NET_7_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_8_Internal_Requirements_Specification', $('#NET_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_8_Internal_Requirements_Specification_D', $('#NET_8_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_9_Cable_Standard_Specification', $('#NET_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_9_Cable_Standard_Specification_D', $('#NET_9_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_10_Rel_Dpt_Groups_Needs', $('#NET_10').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_10_Rel_Dpt_Groups_Needs_D', $('#NET_10_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_11_Incom_Comm_Operator_Location', $('#NET_11').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_11_Incom_Comm_Operator_Location_D', $('#NET_11_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_12_Acces_Critical_Infrastructure', $('#NET_12').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_12_Acces_Critical_Infrastructure_D', $('#NET_12_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_13_Customer_Image_Comm_Network_Operating', $('#NET_13').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_13_Customer_Image_Comm_Network_Operating_D', $('#NET_13_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_14_Equipment_Outside_Connection_Net', $('#NET_14').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_14_Equipment_Outside_Connection_Net_D', $('#NET_14_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_15_Mobile_Covarage_Nesesary', $('#NET_15').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_15_Mobile_Covarage_Nesesary_D', $('#NET_15_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_16_Patch_Cables_Fiber_Copper', $('#NET_16').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_16_Patch_Cables_Fiber_Copper_D', $('#NET_16_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_17_Info', $('#NET_17').val());
    listItem.set_item('NET_17_Info_D', $('#NET_17_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_1_Protection', $('#BRA_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_2_Floor_Ceiling', $('#BRA_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_3_Protection_Volume', $('#BRA_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_4_Fire_Resistance_Density', $('#BRA_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_5_Ventilation', $('#BRA_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_6_Inergen_Pressure_Relief', $('#BRA_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_7_Deviation_Warranties', $('#BRA_7').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_8_Room_Configuration', $('#BRA_8').val());
    listItem.set_item('BRA_9_Info', $('#BRA_9').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_1_Included_Protection_Types', $('#PERI_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_1_Included_Protection_Types_D', $('#PERI_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_2_Building_Protection_Class', $('#PERI_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_2_Building_Protection_Class_D', $('#PERI_2_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_3_NR_Room_Building_Indoors_Outdoors', $('#PERI_3').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_3_NR_Room_Building_Indoors_Outdoors_D', $('#PERI_3_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_4_Protection_Nr_Doors_Passages', $('#PERI_4').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_4_Protection_Nr_Doors_Passages_D', $('#PERI_4_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_5_Perimeter_Locking_System', $('#PERI_5').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_5_Perimeter_Locking_System_D', $('#PERI_5_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_6_Info', $('#PERI_6').val());
    listItem.set_item('PERI_6_Info_D', $('#PERI_6_D').val());
    listItem.update();
    console.log("Knas");
    appContext.load(listItem);
    appContext.executeQueryAsync(success,fail);
    console.log("Knas2");

}


function success() {

    console.log('Success');
    itemId = listItem.get_id();
    console.log("listitem är: " + listItem);
    item = listItem;
}
function fail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Can't get it to work this is what I have now know that it's much but don't know want to do anymore.

John, i have tried your way but haven't got it to work to

```
'use strict';

var appContext, hostweburl, hostContext, parentWeb, list, item, itemId, listId, CTID, listItem, ctTypes, ctName;

appContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
listId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListId"));
itemId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListItemId"));
hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(appContext, hostweburl);
parentWeb = hostContext.get_web();
list = parentWeb.get_lists().getById(listId);
item = list.getItemById(itemId);


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $(document).tooltip();
    $('#GEN_4').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    $('#save').click(setItems);


    if (itemId == 'null') {
        return;

    }
    else {
        appContext.load(item);
        appContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var fieldV = item.get_fieldValues();
            //var d = fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio;
            //d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            $('#Title').val(fieldV.Title);
            $('#GEN_1').val(fieldV.GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment);
            //$('#GEN_4').val(d.toISOString().substr(0, 10));

            //if (fieldV.GEN_19_BYGG_GOLV == true) {
            //    $('#GEN_19_1').attr('checked', 'checked');
            //}
            //else {
            //    $('#GEN_19_2').attr('checked', 'checked');
            //}

            //$('#DRI_6').val(fieldV.DRI_6_Personnel_Servicetype);
        }, fail);

    }

});




function createListItem() {
    console.log("1");

    if (itemId == 'null') {
       ctName = "CoroCoro";
       var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
        var folderName = $('#Title').val();
            if (folderName != "") {
                itemCreateInfo.set_leafName(folderName);
            } else {
                alert('No title');
                return false;
            }
        listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        ctTypes = list.get_contentTypes();
        appContext.load(ctTypes);
        listItem.update();
        appContext.load(listItem, "ContentTypeId");
        appContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var ct;
                var ct_enumerator = ctTypes.getEnumerator();
                while (ct_enumerator.moveNext()) {
                    ct = ct_enumerator.get_current();
                    if (ct.get_name() == ctName) {
                        CTID = ct.get_id();
                    }
                }



            listItem.set_item("ContentTypeId", CTID);
            listItem.update();
            console.log(ctTypes);
            appContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { console.log('success') },fail);
        }, fail);

    }
    else {
        listItem = item;
        console.log("2");
        setItems();
    }
    console.log("13")
}

function setItems() {
    createListItem();
    listItem.set_item('Title', $('#Title').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment', $('#GEN_1').val());
    //listItem.set_item('GEN_4_File_Prio', $('#GEN_4').val());
    //listItem.set_item('GEN_19_BYGG_GOLV', $('input[name="GEN19"]:checked').val());
    //listItem.set_item('DRI_6_Personnel_Servicetype', $("#DRI_6 option:selected").text());
    listItem.update();
    appContext.load(listItem);
    appContext.executeQueryAsync(success,fail);


}


function success() {

    console.log('Success');
    itemId = listItem.get_id();
    console.log("listitem är: " + listItem);
    item = listItem;
}
function fail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Your method is confusing... are you just trying to create a folder? Your code makes it seem like you are attempting to change the content type of a folder to be something else after you create it. If you are only trying to create a folder, the content type change is unnecessary, `set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder)` does that for you.

Comment: When i save an item the content type is name is Folder i have my own content type that with coulmns that i trying to save to and yes it should be a folder i dont know now correct me if i'm wrong but i tought that i needed this?set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder)

Comment: When i remove it i get this message: To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()

Comment: Okay I see what you're doing now, you have a content type that inherits from folder you're trying to set this new folder item to -- I'm pretty sure you'll need that `set_underlyingObjectType` method, let me work out an answer with some more details

Comment: Have you checked to see that your content types are correct? You've got a few different content types that are either check boxes or inputs, etc. Mismatch in type or length can cause an input issue. Try to remove a lot of the field values (maybe leave just Title or any required fields) you're setting and see if it completes. If it does, you've got a content type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me... required a bit of modification and usage of the `update()` statement is required when modifying item properties:

```
var clientContext,
    oWebsite, 
    oList,
    itemCreateInfo,
    newItm,
    ctTypes;

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("<yourListName>");

itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
itemCreateInfo.set_leafName("My new folder!");
newItm = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
ctTypes = oList.get_contentTypes();
clientContext.load(ctTypes);
newItm.update();
clientContext.load(newItm, "ContentTypeId");
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    // get your content type id here instead of mine...
    var mySpecialCtTypeId = ctTypes.getItemAtIndex(2).get_id();
    // assign the title which sharepoint does for you when creating in the UI
    newItm.set_item("Title", "My new folder!");
    // assign your content type id to the "ContentTypeId" field
    newItm.set_item("ContentTypeId", mySpecialCtTypeId);
    newItm.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() { console.log('success') }, function(sender, args) { console.log(args.get_message()) })
}, function(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message()); 
});
```

Note -- I cheated and got my content type ID using a lookup based on the index in the contentType collection, your loop should do the same effectively for you. The `update()` method is required whenever you modify an item using the JS Object Model before you call `executeQueryAsync`. I also load the `newItm` variable before I make the first `executeQueryAsync` so that I can manipulate it in it's new state in the first success callback -- otherwise the content type information wouldn't be avialable.

Not sure where your string error came from! You may want to just modify the question to describe what you're intending to do (create a folder item and assign it a specific content type)

Comment: Hi John thank you for helping me i have tried yout code now and i still get content type folder insteed of mine do think it have to do with the string error? i going to update my question now

Comment: Hmm with so many assignments in your code and two other method calls it is very likely that the error is in there somewhere... start with the basic case: find the ID of the content type you want, then create just one item in a method like the one I posted above that doesn't do any field assignments; then work your way up to all of the assignments and you should eventually find which part of the routine is causing the problem. This is one of those scenarios where it helps to write and test a bit at a time instead of trying to get the whole thing to work after writing it!

Comment: ok going to do that i did success to get the content type one time but i couldnt read it back and then the second time it didnt work -_- starting tio get tired